# Oracle APEX 4.2 Charts Custom XML IF ELSE IF Not Working

Tags: xml, oracle-apex

I  defined cdata format of oracle apex bar chart tooltip value based on IF ELSE IF but no text shown in tooltip , tooltip apears without text 
[image]
XML Code I am specifying is :

```
   <tooltip_settings enabled="true">           
    <IF>
        <Condition %SeriesName="Last_YR_CUR_MON_TD?"> 
            <format><![CDATA[{%Name}{enabled:False} - {%Value}{numDecimals:0,decimalSeparator:.,thousandsSeparator:\,} (&P4_LAST_YR_CUR_MON_ALIAS.)]]></format>
        </Condition>
    </IF>
    <ELSE>

            <format><![CDATA[{%Name}{enabled:False} - {%Value}{numDecimals:0,decimalSeparator:.,thousandsSeparator:\,} (&P4_CUR_YR_CUR_MON_ALIAS.)]]></format>

    </ELSE>
 </tooltip_settings>
```

Is there syntax problem of IF ELSE IF?
What is the syntax of IF ELSE IF Condition in XML?

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this.

```
<IF something>
    <some actions>
<THEN something>
    <some actions>
</THEN>
<ELSE something>
    <some actions>
</ELSE>
</IF>
```